# Showing that a sequence is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to show that the set {$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}$} for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not compact but I am not sure what to pick as a sequence. Does this sequence work, $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}$ and then this would converge to 1 but then any subsequence must converge to 1, but 1 is not in the set. This would imply that the set is not compact.

Also, my definition of compact is as follows: a set A is compact if any sequence in A has a subsequence that converges to a point in A

Comment: Explain how you get that your proposed $x_n$ converges to $1$.

Comment: @EricTowers Well, if we take the limit of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ it is going to 0.

Comment: You have defined $x_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @abmar I am not sure where you got the pi over 6. Then, do I need a summation in this case before I can define a sequence.

Comment: See this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem. Also, the above is wrong, it should be $\pi^2 / 6$.

Comment: @abmar Oh, okay I see. I have never seen this before. Then does my approach not work?

Comment: @abmar : I think you mean $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  Of the various indicated sums, each exceeds $\frac{\pi}{6}$ with its first term.

Comment: @Sam Your approach works, but you have to show instead that $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is not in the set.

Comment: @kccu So, my sequence does work? Well, its clear that is not in the sequence because it is irrational.

Comment: @Sam That's exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the definition to prove this set is not compact, show that $\{(0,r) : r\in \left(0,\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\}$ form an open cover to this set which has no finite sub-cover.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned my definition of compact is a set A is compact if any sequence in A has a subsequence that converges to a point in A.

Comment: @Sam : Yes.  That would be an excellent thing to edit into your question.

Comment: @Sam: Your sequence (of rationals) is strictly increasing and converges to $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6},$ which is not a rational. Hence you have no sub-sequences  convergent in the set.

Comment: @Nil Are you referring to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If a set of real numbers $K$ is compact then $a =$ GLB of $K$ and $b =$ LUB of $K$ both belong to $K$ so $K \subset [a,b]$ and $a \in K$ and $b \in K$. So you don't need to know anything about a series that converges to $\pi/6$ - just demonstrate that the LUB can't belong to your set of real numbers.